# Changing CSS code to specific javascript codefile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am developing a timer that needs to be a js code file.I have css code as below to implement the hour and minute hand on the clock.I need to change this specific code into separate js file using styled components using CSS animations.How can I do it?

```
.minute {

  transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(calc(var(--start-minutes) * 6deg));

  stroke-width: 0.6;

  animation: rotateMinuteHand 3600s steps(60) infinite;

  animation-delay: calc(var(--start-seconds) * -1 * 1s);

}



.hour {

  transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(calc(var(--start-hours) * 30deg));

  animation: rotateHourHand calc(12 * 60 * 60s) linear infinite;

  stroke-width: 1;

  animation-delay: calc(calc(var(--start-minutes) * -60 * 1s) + calc(var(--start-seconds) * -1 * 1s));

}
 keyframes rotateMinuteHand {

  from {

    transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(calc(var(--start-minutes) * 6deg));

  }

  to {

    transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(calc(var(--start-minutes) * 6deg + 360deg));

  }

}



@keyframes rotateHourHand {

  from {

    transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(calc(var(--start-hours) * 30deg));

  }

  to {

    transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(calc(var(--start-hours) * 30deg + 360deg));

  }

}
```

This is the code that I tried for Minute hand.However this does not seem write to me for code "animation-delay: calc(var(--start-minutes) * -1 * 1s);"

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'

const rotateMinuteHand = props => keyframes`
    from {
      transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(${(props.startMinutes-33)*6}deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(${(props.startMinutes-33)*6+360}deg);
    }
`

  
const Minute = styled.line`
    transform: ${props => `translate(20px, 20px) rotate(${(props.minutes-33)*6}deg)`};
    stroke-width: 0.6;
    animation: ${props => {const kf = rotateMinuteHand(props); console.log(kf); return kf}} 3600s steps(60) infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--start-minutes) * -1 * 1s);
    
`

export default Minute;
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#animations) for animations? Otherwise, can you provide an example of your attempt?

Comment: @DrewReese Please see the edited code below which I tried

Comment: Other than `styled.line` not being valid for me (had to change to `div`) the above code works for me in a codesandbox. Can you provide a running codesandbox that reproduces your issue?